# Filling a 2d array with manhattan distance pattern

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do this homework for algorithms, they ask me to fill a two-dimensional array of int like this:

```
4 3 2 3 4
3 2 1 2 3
2 1 0 1 2
3 2 1 2 3
4 3 2 3 4
```

I tried this in java:

```
int[][] array = new int[5][5];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        array[i][j] = Math.abs(i - j);
    }
}
```

but it gives me something like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 0 1 2 3
2 1 0 1 3
3 2 1 0 1
4 3 2 1 0
```

And it's not really the same thing, but it's the closest that I found. I wrote the code in java but it can be in any other language... the important is the "formula" I think. So if you can help me resolving this trouble it'll be nice, I tried to look for the code online but I didn't find anything... thank you.

Comment: First you have to be able to calculate the number by hand, before you can calculate it with a computer program. So number in each cell is Manhattan distance to the center. Look up how to calculate Manhattan distance, then calculate by hand to make sure you get same results as the example, then just convert the calculation to code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as if you're looking for the distance to the center. So you first have to calculate this point:

```
int center = array.length / 2; //assuming a quadratic array
```

Then, calculating the distance is quite easy:

```
//for ...
array[i][j] = Math.abs(i - center) + Math.abs(j - center);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will also work.

```
int p=N-1;
for(i=0,l=N-1;i<=l;i++,l--)
{
    for(j=0,k=N-1;j<=k;j++,k--)
    {
        arr[i][j]=p;
        arr[i][k]=p;
        arr[l][j]=p;
        arr[l][k]=p;
        p--;
    }
    p=N-i-2;
}
```